# Complete form by url

Tags: html, string, forms, url, fill

I need to complete a form using a query string in the URL, but the problem is that by putting the basic shape (page.php?title=value&title2=value) is not complete. The form is pre-filled by reading values ​​from a MYSQL database. It is the code:

```
<form action="change.php" method="post">
Titulo:<br />
<input name="titulo" type="text" value="'.$row_show['titulo'].'"size="120" maxlenght="50"/><br /><br />
Banner URL:<br />
<input name="banner" type="text" value="'.$row_show['banner'].'"size="120"/><br /><br />
Link:<br />
<input name="link" type="text" value="'.$row_show['link'].'"size="120"/><br /><br />
Descripcion:<br />
<input name="descripcion" type="text" value="'.$row_show['descripcion'].'"size="120" maxlenght="70"/><br /><br />
Disponibilidad:<br />
<input name="disponibilidad" type="text" value="'.$row_show['disponibilidad'].'"size="120"/><br /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$row_show['id'].'" />
<br />
<input type="submit" class="proofbutton" name="modificar" value="MODIFICAR ADSPACE" />
</form>
```

I need insert in this form other values but I have no need to remove the default values.

e.g. change.php?titulo=Nick&descripcion=test%20fill

Sorry for my bad english. Thanks

Comment: What do you wish to do with the default values after the POST to change.php?

Comment: update the values of the database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the browser would not forward all input data, but try using javascript to submit the form, and see if that works. Something like:

```
<a href="javascript:this.parentNode.submit()">Submit</a>
```

Instead of adding default values to the query string, you may want to consider determining whether or not they are specified on the receiving end, and if not, using the default value then.

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach... Store any default values in their own uniquely named hidden field on your page.php.  Then when you post to change.php you can write logic that determines which values should be saved.

Comment: The problem is it wont let me add more than one value, because previously I select another option is to display the form, meaning that the page would look like: change.php?adspace=1&title=example&banner=example

Comment: Then it sounds like you want your form method to be a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: they not works sorry i have been change post by get and is the same